# DataTable copy exception

Tags: c#, datatable

I have DataTable, there are a lot of threads to fill this table(for each column), so I had many troubles. Now every thread suppose to work with Copy of table, but when I call

```
                MainTableCopy = new DataTable();
                lock (MainTable)
                    MainTableCopy = MainTable.Copy();
```

it throws an exception like "The column "MName" is constrained by uniqueness. The value of "Item 12" already exists."
MainTable have same settings and every value in "MName" is unique.

What I'm doing wrong? Where MainTableCopy take clone of row, that unique in MainTable?

P.S. I know I can just make copy row by row, but in this case I want to understand, what exactly happens.

Threads to fill table

```
                DataTable MainTableCopy = new DataTable();
                lock (MainTable)
                    MainTableCopy = MainTable.Copy();

                foreach (DataRow row in MainTableCopy.Rows)
                {
                    //Getting info
                    DataRow Drw = null;
                    while (Drw == null)
                        Drw = MainTable.Rows.Find(name);
                        lock (Drw)
                        {
                            Drw.SetField("MProfit", 0);
                            //Fill data
                        }
                 }
```

Comment: Do you have the table as part of a DATASET?  Are there restrictions based on something like "Key" Uniqueness column expectations?

Comment: Yes, MainTable is part of MainSet. Only restriction for MainTable is unique "MName" column(couse it's primary key)

Comment: That's your problem.  You have other threads adding records for a given MName without pre-confirming it does not already exist.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But I put lock (MainTable) to prevent it. If it's not working, how to make it correct? Actually MainTable built one time when starts, all "MName" is unique and I don't add any rows at all.

Comment: Can you describe context of other threads working with this one main table.  Purpose of your operation so I and others may get a head wrapped around possible solution.

Comment: There are 16 columns. Every thread filling it's own column with numbers(4 threads). And 2 threads are comparing the values and put result on specific column(unique for every this 2 thread).

Comment: Edit your original post, not comments.  Show some BASIC constructs of what you are trying to do... sample of what the data in the table represents, even if you are just space-aligning the sample data in your edit.. Thread 1 updating XXX, Thread 2 updates YYY, Thread 3 updates total of XXX + YYY, etc.